# How to instantly change between the actions of a same link without refreshing the page? Creating a FB like feature

Tags: ember.js

I am building a 'Watch this deal' functionality, which is similar to FB 'like' feature. (Ember version 1.13)

Here is the scenario:

There is an icon beside every deal which will enable the current user to 'watch' or 'not watch' the deal. The actions are completed and working and changes on the UI is also working fine. The problem is, when I click on that icon, I become a watcher of the deal but the icon doesn't change. I have to refresh the page to see that change.

controller:

```
actions:{
   // add and remove watchers

addToWatcher: function(deal) {
    var _this = this;
    var currentUser = this.get('currentUser');
    deal.get('watchers').addObject(currentUser);
    deal.save().then(function () {
      Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').success("You are now watching");
    }, function() {
      // Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').danger('apiFailure');
    });
},

removeWatcher: function(deal) {
    var _this = this;
    var currentUser = this.get('currentUser');
    deal.get('watchers').removeObject(currentUser);
    deal.save().then(function () {
      Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').success("You are now watching");
    }, function() {
      // Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').danger('apiFailure');
    });
}
}
```

templates:

```
      {{#if (check-watcher deal currentUser.id)}}
         <i class="fa fa-2x sc-icon-watch watched" {{action 'removeWatcher' deal}} style="padding: 5px 10px;"></i><br>
      {{else}}
         <i class="fa fa-2x sc-icon-watch" {{action 'addToWatcher' deal}} style="padding: 5px 10px;"></i><br>
      {{/if}}
```

Here check-watcher is a helper I wrote to check if the deal is being watched by the current user. If it is, the icon will be Red and clicking on it again will trigger 'removeWatcher' action. If not, icon will be black and clicking on it will make user watch the deal.

check-watcher helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function checkWatcher(object, currentUser) {
  var currentUser = object[1];
  var watchers = object[0].get('watchers').getEach('id');
  if (watchers.contains(currentUser)) {
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(checkWatcher);
```

If I were to just change the class, that would have been easy, but I have to change the action too in the views, that's where it's a little tricky.

So, how to make the change in UI happen between adding and removing watchers without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, [you need to define](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html) a `compute` method for the helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function checkWatcher(object, currentUser) {
  var currentUser = object[1];
  var watchers = object[0].get('watchers').getEach('id');
  if (watchers.contains(currentUser)) {
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}

export default Ember.Helper.extend({ compute: checkWatcher });
```

In that case, the helper will recompute its output every time the input changes.

And there is not need to change an action in a template. You could always call 'toggleWatcher' action from template, and then decide what to do in the controller:

```
toggleWatcher(deal) {
  var currentUser = this.get('currentUser');

  if (deal.get('watchers').contains(currentUser)) {
    this.send('removeWatcher', deal);
  } else {
    this.send('addToWatcher', deal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Compute worked! Plus your hint "the helper will recompute its output every time the input changes." helped as I changed the parameters I was sending to the helper. Awesome!